# Include process in unit test and code coverage?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage

I'm trying to find a code coverage solution for an installation of Visual Studio 2015 to be executed from a build server (Visual Studio Team Services / TFS).

Inside the solution of my project I have unit tests that are collecting code coverage information, but I'm not getting complete coverage from traditional unit tests alone.  I've created a unit test that starts a process and gets screenshots of a 3D scene and diffs them versus ones that are human verified.

I can get the process to run off of the same assemblies as the unit test, but I'm not sure how to get the code coverage result from the process and then merge it with the active unit test run.

Am I approaching this the wrong way or is there a way to get the coverage results from the process run and merge them with the rest of the unit test code coverage results before TFS publishes the test results?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this blog, it may be helpful.[How to: Obtain Code Coverage Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182496(v=vs.100).aspx)

Running VSPerfMon.exe can interact with the collection of code coverage data